# Makefile: How to export environment variable to shell before target?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I would like to pass makefile variable value to shell variable value:

.makerc:

```
IP:=0.0.0.0
```

Makefile:

```
-include: .makerc
export IP

all:
    printenv | grep IP
```

I just want IP variable value appear as IP environment variable in shell. I don't want to do this in a target. It has to be off-target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your makefile:

```
-include: .makerc
```

is wrong: `include` is a keyword not a target.  This should be:

```
-include .makerc
```

(no colon).

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been going mad for hour in here. Such a stupid mistake. Well, at least my question is quite simple, lot simpler than other questions in here about exporting variable to shell.